# Integer value comparison

Tags: java, integer, int, equals, autoboxing

I'm a newbie Java coder and I just read a variable of an integer class can be described three different ways in the API.  I have the following code:

```
if (count.compareTo(0)) { 
            System.out.println(out_table);
            count++;
    }
```

This is inside a loop and just outputs `out_table`.
My goal is to figure out how to see if the value in integer `count > 0`.

I realize the `count.compare(0)` is the correct way? or is it `count.equals(0)`?

I know the `count == 0` is incorrect. Is this right? Is there a value comparison operator  where its just `count=0`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Integers are autounboxed, so you can just do

```
if (count > 0) {
    .... 
}
```

Comment: Ummm. Not really. ... In other comparisons this is not always the case. What if you are comparing two Integers and using '=='? Then the instances are compared, but sometimes the JVM doesn't cache them so it reports identical values as different. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002037/comparing-integer-values-in-java-strange-behavior .

Comment: @ingyhere Integer is autounboxed when comparing with int.

Comment: @Alex78191: In the case of one boxed and one primitive comparison in this example it works, and the left-most value unboxes. This is not guaranteed for comparisons of two Integer objects, at least not in 2013 nor in all JVM implementations. That was the point, if I recall. Anyway, there's little cost to using `if (count.intValue() > 0) { ... }` as a practice except it may be beneficial to _limit_ autounboxing in loops.

Answer (score 30):

To figure out if an `Integer` is greater than 0, you can:

- check if `compareTo(O)` returns a positive number:

  ```
  if (count.compareTo(0) > 0)
       ...
  ```

  But that looks pretty silly, doesn't it? Better just...
- use [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)<sup>1</sup>:

  ```
  if (count > 0)
      ....
  ```

  This is equivalent to:

  ```
  if (count.intValue() > 0)
      ...
  ```

  It is important to note that "`==`" is evaluated like this, with the `Integer` operand unboxed rather than the `int` operand boxed. Otherwise, `count == 0` would return false when `count` was initialized as `new Integer(0)` (because "`==`" tests for reference equality).

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the first example uses [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) (before Java 1.5 you couldn't pass an `int` to `compareTo`) and the second example uses [unboxing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8). The combined feature is often simply called "autoboxing" for short, which is often then extended into calling both types of conversions "autoboxing". I apologize for my lax usage of terminology.

Comment: The former example is using autoboxing; the latter autounboxing.

Comment: +1: Regarding the `==` comparison, one should be very cautious when comparing *two* *boxed* numbers (but not one boxed and one primitive number), because, as mmyers mentioned, `==` tests for reference equality, not equality of the wrapped values.

Answer (score 13):

It's better to avoid unnecessary autoboxing for 2 reasons.

For one thing, it's a bit slower than `int < int`, as you're (sometimes) creating an extra object;

```
void doSomethingWith(Integer integerObject){ ...
  int i = 1000;
  doSomethingWith(i);//gets compiled into doSomethingWith(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

The bigger issue is that hidden autoboxing can hide exceptions:

```
void doSomethingWith (Integer count){
  if (count>0)  // gets compiled into count.intValue()>0
```

Calling this method with `null` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

The split between primitives and wrapper objects in java was always described as a kludge for speed. Autoboxing almost hides this, but not quite - it's cleaner just to keep track of the type. So if you've got an Integer object, you can just call `compare()` or `intValue()`, and if you've got the primitive just check the value directly.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the negative sides of autounboxing. The performance difference can be huge, especially when auto(un)boxing in loops.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use equals:

```
 Integer a = 0;

 if (a.equals(0)) {
     // a == 0
 }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
 if (a.intValue() == 0) {
     // a == 0
 }
```

and also:

```
 if (a == 0) {

 }
```

(the Java compiler automatically adds **intValue**())

Note that autoboxing/autounboxing can introduce a significant overhead (especially inside loops).

Answer (score 3):

Although you could certainly use the `compareTo` method on an Integer instance, it's not clear when reading the code, so you should probably avoid doing so.

Java allows you to use autoboxing (see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to compare directly with an int, so you can do:

```
if (count > 0) { }
```

And the `Integer` instance `count` gets automatically converted to an `int` for the comparison.

If you're having trouble understanding this, check out the link above, or imagine it's doing this:

```
if (count.intValue() > 0) { }
```

Comment: up vote for informative links.

Keep in mind that `count` has to be non-null. The Exception produced at runtime auto-unboxing a null value is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to watch out for is if the second value was another Integer object instead of a literal '0', the '==' operator compares the object pointers and will not auto-unbox.

ie:

```
Integer a = new Integer(0);   
Integer b = new Integer(0);   
int c = 0;

boolean isSame_EqOperator = (a==b); //false!
boolean isSame_EqMethod = (a.equals(b)); //true
boolean isSame_EqAutoUnbox = ((a==c) && (a.equals(c)); //also true, because of auto-unbox

//Note: for initializing a and b, the Integer constructor 
// is called explicitly to avoid integer object caching 
// for the purpose of the example.
// Calling it explicitly ensures each integer is created 
// as a separate object as intended.
// Edited in response to comment by @nolith
```

Comment: You must instantiate `a` and `b` with `New Integer(0)` otherwise `isSame_EqOperator` will be `true`

Comment: Goodpoint @nolith, though this is due to caching of integers in Java, explained well in the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java. I will change my answer to use your suggested edit with a comment describing why to explicitly use the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

well i might be late on this but i would like to share something:

Given the input:
    System.out.println(isGreaterThanZero(-1));

```
public static boolean isGreaterThanZero(Integer value) {
    return value == null?false:value.compareTo(0) > 0;
}
```

Returns **false**

```
public static boolean isGreaterThanZero(Integer value) {
    return value == null?false:value.intValue() > 0;
}
```

Returns true
So i think in yourcase 'compareTo' will be more accurate.