# java == operator

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird Java Boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-java-boxing)

Hi,

Can somebody explain why the last print returns false ?

```
int a = 100;
int b = 100;

System.out.println(a == b); // prints true

Integer aa = 100;
Integer bb = 100;

System.out.println(aa == bb); // prints true

Integer aaa = 1000;
Integer bbb = 1000;

System.out.println(aaa == bbb); // prints false
```

Thanks
Michael

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-java-boxing

Comment: Yes, this is a dupe many times over.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java-closed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why the second print evaluates to true is because the first 128 Integer objects are cached by the Integer class.  You want to use .`equals`

Comment: Yeah, this is the right answer.  See this also:  http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas  "Immutable Objects/Wrapper Class Caching"

Comment: This is probably my number one disliked "feature" of Java. Talk about inconsistencies.

Comment: I would really like to be able to explicitly disable initialization autoboxing.

Comment: I suspect they did this for performance.  If you stick to using valueOf you won't get stung, but I agree it's inconsistent.

Comment: IMO, anyone who uses `==` to compare values of *any* `Object` is asking to get burned.

Comment: Oh but we're so clever with String interning and == and...I smell smoke.

Comment: This applies only to autoboxed object, not to the explicitly created ones.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two Integer objects, which using the == operator compares the two references, instead of the two values.

Use the `equals()` method to be sure you're comparing both values.

Comment: what abput `System.out.println(aa == bb);`

Comment: -1 since aa == bb prints true.

Comment: +1 because this is all correct, even if it doesn't fully explain.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Integer.compareTo` for testing numerical equality for `Integer` objects.  The `==` operator is comparing the objects, not the numbers.

Comment: You can use Integer.equals as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `Integer` objects are *autoboxed* using the method `Integer.valueOf(int)`. Have a look at the documentation of that method. Then everything should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be using is `aaa.equals(bbb)`. In Java using == on objects compares whether they are the same *instance* of the object instead of whether they are equal according to their `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the second case return `true`. But that why in [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) they advise against mixing the use of Wrapper classes and the `==` operator.

Take a look at this class and code:

```
public class RichardInt {
    private int value;
    public RichardInt(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

What would be the result of the following?

```
RichardInt aa = new RichardInt(100);
RichardInt bb = new RichardInt(100);
System.out.println(aa == bb); // prints false
```

It prints false because the equals operator `==` compares references when used with objects. Remember, in Java, objects are reference types, while primitives (like `int`) are value types. (note: can someone let me know if I'm misusing "value type"? I have a feeling I am.) The following would print true:

```
RichardInt aa = new RichardInt(100);
RichardInt bb = aa;
System.out.println(aa == bb); // prints true
```

... since `aa` and `bb` reference the same instance of `RichardInt`.

So maybe the above behavior is easier to understand in the following example...

```
Intger aaa = new Intger(1000);
Intger bbb = new Integer(1000);
System.out.println(aaa == bbb); // prints false
```

In more recent versions of Java, the wrapper classes (`Integer` and `Float` and `Boolean` etc...) can auto-box, meaning you can do the following:

```
Integer aa = 1000;
// this is a shorthand for...
// Integer aa = new Integer(1000);
```

But it leads to confusing behavior when you try things like this:

```
Integer aaa = 1000;
Integer bbb = 1000;
System.out.println(aaa == bbb); // prints false
```

Or even better, you can end up with puzzles like this...

```
// what values of x and y will result in output?
if(!(x<y)&&!(x>y)&&!(x==y)) {
    System.out.println("How is this possible?");
}
```

In the end, whenever dealing with objects, you'll want to use `.equals()` instead of `==`.

```
Integer aaa = 1000;
Integer bbb = 1000;
System.out.println(aaa.equals(bbb)); // prints true
```