# How to convert int to Integer

Tags: android

```
private static HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> mBitmapCache;         
mBitmapCache.put(R.drawable.bg1,object);
```

`R.drawable.bg1` is an `int` ... but i want to convert into `Integer` because `Hashmap` takes an `Integer`... and when draw the multiple objects in seconds , it creates a Integer Object runtime 
which affects the performence of the code...

Answer (score 76):

```
int iInt = 10;
Integer iInteger = Integer.valueOf(iInt);
```

P.S. Answer edited due to comments pointing out an issue with initial suggested solution.

Comment: "You should not call the constructor for wrapper classes 
 directly, such as`new Integer(42)`. Instead, call the valueOf 
 factory method, such as Integer.valueOf(42). This will 
 typically use less memory because common integers such 
 as 0 and 1 will share a single instance."

Integer iInteger = Integer.valueOf(iInt);

Comment: i think this is done automatically, thus you could have somethink like `Integer iInteger = iInt;` and it should work.

Comment: I just wanted to share https://stackoverflow.com/q/3131136/384674 for "You should not call constructor..."

Comment: Just for curiosity, is `Integer value = (Integer) intValue;` a bad practise? Or, it's not recommended for int to Integer conversion?

Comment: It is bad practice to convert it through the wrapper classes directly.

Comment: @SimranSharma you are wrong see this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088328/directly-casting-primitive-type-to-object-is-fine-in-java

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar, I guess you haven't seen the edits to this answer. The older answer used the constructor of the wrapper class to convert it. Somewhat like this `new Integer(int);`. Using wrapper class in this way to cast is a bad practice. You should use `Integer.valueOf(int)` instead. It is a function built for this purpose and is more reliable and efficient.

Comment: @SimranSharma You are correct about new Integer(int); This one is bad practice. But Integer value = (Integer) intValue; is not a bad practice. It is Autoboxing that is what I want to say.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar, absolutely that is not a bad practice. I said it because, in the previous edit, he used `new Integer(int);`. But, I feel when there is a method that is provided dedicated for one purpose, it always makes more sense to use the method instead. I feel it always works out to be more efficient that way (in general, not being specific to Integer casting).

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned, one way is to use

```java
int original = 32;
Integer converted = new Integer(original);
```

But *you should not call the constructor for wrapper classes directly*. It is a poor practice to do so. Instead, use the methods pre-defined especially for this purpose.

So, the new code would look like this (recommended):

```java
mBitmapCache.put(Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.bg1), object);
```

Comment: Is there a reason "you should not call the constructor for wrapper classes directly"?

Comment: Not really - it is just a guess that the dev did not have an urge to create new object on every call.

Rarely the case: You would use new Integer() if you want to distinguish several Integer objects.
Mostly the case: You are using Integer and not int just because you want to also have *null* value. Integer.valueOf() would return you the same object on multiple calls in particular scenario, which will save memory (never the case with new Integer()).

Comment: I just wanted to share https://stackoverflow.com/q/3131136/384674 for "You should not call constructor..."

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem . For this you can use a Hashmap which takes "string" and "object" as shown in code below:

```
/** stores the image database icons */
public static int[] imageIconDatabase = { R.drawable.ball,
        R.drawable.catmouse, R.drawable.cube, R.drawable.fresh,
        R.drawable.guitar, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.teapot,
        R.drawable.india, R.drawable.thailand, R.drawable.netherlands,
        R.drawable.srilanka, R.drawable.pakistan,

};
private void initializeImageList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < imageIconDatabase.length; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("Name", imageNameDatabase[i]);
        map.put("Icon", imageIconDatabase[i]);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is by using following 
`Integer obj = new Integer(primitiveValue)`
or in your case `new Integer(R.drawable.bg1)`.
The only problem with this is it would unnecessarily create an objects during runtime.

If you are using JDK 5 or above you can exercise power of Autoboxing.
Lets keep that aside for a while.

Within class Integer (java.lang.Integer) we do have many methods one of which is:
`static Integer valueOf(int)` it returns value of an int as a Integer.

So a `Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.bg1)` could work.

Answer (score -4):

i it integer, int to Integer

```
Integer intObj = new Integer(i);
```

add to collection

```
list.add(String.valueOf(intObj));
```

Comment: When your trying to answer a question which has is already being answered. Add more information to the answer so that it adds value.