# Directly casting primitive type to object is fine in Java?

Tags: java, android

I am directly casting my int primitive type variable to Integer object like below:

```
int intValue = 0;
Integer value = (Integer) intValue;
```

Is this fine or will cause some unexpected problems?

Comment: It is fine. See: [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Is there not any need to call any method like Integer.valueOf() for this purpose?

Comment: No, the point of autoboxing is that this happens automatically when you assign an `int` to an `Integer`. Note: The cast in your code is unnecessary, you could just to `Integer value = intvalue;`. Read the page about autoboxing (link above), it explains it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
> between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
> classes.

```
int intValue = 0;
Integer value = intValue; // by Autoboxing
```

you can also convert it using valueOf method of wrapper class

```
Integer value = Integer.valueOf(intValue)
```

Check [What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/408661/3022836) if you still have doubts.