# Semantics of “==” operator in Java

Tags: java

I was wondering: Why does this code result in `false`?
Coz `==` operator should return `true` when it's the same memory point.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = new String("hello");

    System.out.println(a == "hello");
}
```

- Can you describe why this happens.

Comment: You answered your own question: "It should return true when it's the same memory point". Clearly it isn't the same memory point.

Comment: This question is asked around 100 times a day. There should be an auto answer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals are created on what is called: **Pool Memory**.

However, when one creates a String with explicitly `new` keyword, he actually creates a **new String object**, independent of the pool memory's one. Meaning that both references are not the same at all.

In your sample, you could solve the case by both ways:

_ use `java.lang.String.intern` method: placing your explicitly created String into the pool memory.

_ use only literals to create/reuse `String`.

For information, Pool Memory was created in order to avoid some useless creation of common/redundant literal Strings, thus optimizing memory space.

Similar concept exists for Integer: [Integer caching in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java)

Comment: Actually, from Java 7 onwards, the string pool is in the main heap: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6962931, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes

Comment: @Stephen C Oh :) I didn't know.

Answer (score 5):

Java compares references when you compare (`==`) objects. Since you create two new objects, they do have different addresses in memory regardless of their content.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. In the first instance the OP creates a `new String`. In the second instance the OP uses a `String` literal. So `System.out.println("hello" == "hello");` would in fact return `true`. Might be worth mentioning `String` interning.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that is correct but this is not the case here. He intetionally creates a new string everytime.

Comment: It's the statement `System.out.println(a == "hello");` I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because there are two String objects here - first is the literal and the other is the one created with `new String`. When you create explicitly a new String object it the String from pool is not reused.
It is well described in details http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/strings/string-literal-pool/

Answer (score 0):

The command `String a = new String("hello");` creates a String object in the non-pool part of the memory, and then `a` refers to it. And then `"hello"` is placed in the `String` pool. Whereas while comparing, `a == "hello"` the "hello", is in the String pool. So, the reference of both the objects are different, although the content of both the objects is same. Had to declared `a`, in the following manner, the comparison would had returned `true`

```
String a = "hello";
```