# What causes java to treat this two object types of ArrayLists and Integers differently?

Tags: java

Both ArrayList and Integer are object data type, but why the code below treats the two differently? 
ar,br,a and b are all objects.
Changing ar changes br, but changing a did not change b why? Isn't it both ArrayLists and Integers are objects? assignign an object to another object by using = statement simply does the shallow copy FOR BOTH? or no?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        ArrayList<Integer> br = ar;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(br.toArray()));// [1,2,3]
        ar.remove(0);// lets change ar
        // now lets see if br changed too
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(br.toArray()));// [2,3] (yes did)

        Integer a= new Integer (5);

        Integer b = a;

        a = a+1;// lets change a and see if b changed too

        System.out.println(b);// b is still 5

        //So changing ar changed br too, but changing a did not change b why? Ist it both br and b are objects?




    }
}
```

Comment: The clue is that you wrote `a = ...`.  What does `=` do?

Comment: Here's a topic to read for all clever people that downvoted my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java

Comment: @Lucas: Your answer was downvoted because it was incorrect.  Values are indeed cached, but that has nothing to do with the behaviour observed here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The same = that you are referring to was used in br=ar, b=a, ... now what?

Comment: Yes, but did you do `a.setValue(a + 1)` or something else?

Comment: @Cgraphics: Yes, but what does it **do**?  In general, if you write `a = X; b = a; a = c;` do you expect the value of `b` to be altered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Integer objects are actually [boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) primitives. When you call `Integer a= new Integer (5);`, you create a new Integer. When you execute `Integer b = a;`, then b refers to the *same* instance of Integer as a.

When you call `a = a+1;`, the following happens:

1. a is unboxed into a primitive `int` with value 5.
2. The result of adding one to that `int` is evaluated.
3. The result, 6, is boxed into a *new* `Integer` that has a value of 6. The original integer of value 5 is not modified.

In the case of the list, you are assigning both `ar` and `br` to refer to the *same* instance of  `java.util.ArrayList`. Modifications to that arraylist are seen when you access it through both `ar` and `br`.

The critical point is that `a = a+1` constructs a new `java.lang.Integer()` through unboxing, evaluation, and boxing, while `ar.remove(0);` affects that list without creating a new copy of it.

More JLS reading:

> If p is a value of type int, then boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class and type Integer, such that `r.intValue() == p`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between variables, reference values (and dereferencing for field access and method invocation), and objects.

A variable is just a holder for a value.

A reference value is a value which is interpreted as the location of an object.

An object is ... an object. It has accessible fields and invocable methods.

Here

```
ArrayList <Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
ArrayList<Integer> br = ar;
```

You create two variables which store a single reference value which points to the single instance created with `new ArrayList<>(..)`. So both variables are referencing the same object.

When you invoke a method by using a method invocation expression

```
ar.remove(..);
```

the JVM uses the reference value to find the object and invokes its method. This is the same object referenced by `br`. So when you then do

```
br.toArray()
```

you're still accessing the same object.

Here

```
Integer a = new Integer (5);  
Integer b = a;
```

you create two variables that are referencing the same object.

Then you do

```
 a = a+1;// lets change a and see if b changed too
```

which assigns (`=`) a new reference value to the variable `a`. So now `a` references a different object than `b`.

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
ArrayList <Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
ArrayList<Integer> br = ar;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(br.toArray()));// [1,2,3]
```

`ar` and `br` are the same instance

```
ar.remove(0);// lets change ar
// now lets see if br changed too
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(br.toArray()));// [2,3] (yes did)
```

The *content* of `ar` is changed. Since `ar == br`, the change can be seen in `br`.

```
Integer a = new Integer (5);
Integer b = a;
```

`a` is a new object, and again `b` is assigned to be the same instance

```
a = a+1; // lets change a and see if b changed too
System.out.println(b);  // b is still 5
```

The reference of `a` is changed. `a` now points to a newly created object. `b` still points to the first created object.

Answer (score -3):

this was just asked, earlier today, the Integer b is immutable and wont change, but the arraylist is just a reference...

Comment: This is nothing to do with immutability.