# Why same values got from ArrayList are changed to different ones?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using Java ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(-129);
list.add(-129);
return (list.get(0) == list.get(1));
```

The return value is false.
I know it must be some range problem since when I use -128, it returns true.
But could someone tell me the reason of it?

Comment: You're checking reference equality. Use `.equals()` instead. -128 works because it's in the range of cached values.

Comment: If so, why -128 gives true?

Comment: Integer caching - look at my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integers caching in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java [caches integers](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/boxing_and_caches_integer_valueof) in the range -128..127 (signed bytes). It saves a lot of allocations of tiny numbers which is very common in lots of code. If you use `equals()` instead of `==`, it will work. The `==` check is comparing that two `int` types, that have been magically boxed (i.e. converted) to `Integer` are the same reference - which they are not. But `int` in the signed byte range will be the same. The `equals` check will actually compare the *value* of the variables:

```
return (list.get(0).equals(list.get(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform:
list.add(-129);
list.add(-129);

It create two separate object with separate memory location.when you perform == it return false.
In Java, values from -128 to 127 are cached, so the same objects are returned and you will get true.

For more information see:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparison-autoboxed-integer-objects-java/

Answer (score -1):

If two references point to two different objects, then in accordance with the "= =" to judge both is unequal, even though both have the same reference content. As we know, if two references refer to the same object, in accordance with the "= =" to judge the two are equal.

If you go to the Integer. Java classes, you will find that there is a internal private class IntegerCache. Java, it caches from all the Integer object - between 128 ~ 127.

So the thing is, all the small integers are in the internal cache.
If the value is between 128 ~ 127, then it will be returned from a cache instance,point to the same object.