# Java Integer Comparison

Tags: java

```js
Integer a = 100, b = 100;
Integer c = 1000, d = 1000;
System.out.println(a == b);
System.out.println(c == d);
```

The output of the above code is:

```js
true
false
```

Can someone explain why so?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131136/integers-caching-in-java

Comment: 100 is cached, 1000 is not

Comment: Integer is not a primitive type, don't use `==` to compare values with non-primitive type.