# LinkedList can't copy some duplicate number

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm creating a program using LinkedList that could copy duplicate numbers to a new instance of linkedList.

Let's say `List<Integer> orig = new LinkedList<>()` consists of these numbers: 23,1000,1000,1,23
I want to copy the duplicate numbers to `List<Integer> copy = new LinkedList<>()` which supposed to be 23 and 1000 because I have 2 duplicate numbers. I tried testing it in an array and it works. But not sure why it won't work in LinkedList.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    list1.add(23);
    list1.add(1000);
    list1.add(1000);
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(23);
    List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int x = 0; x <= list1.size()-1; x++) {
        for(int y = x+1; y <= list1.size()-1; y++) {
            if(list1.get(x)==list1.get(y)) {
                list2.add(list1.get(x));
            }
        }
    }

    for(int y = 0; y <= list2.size()-1; y++) {
        System.out.println(list2.get(y));
    }
```

- Current OUTPUT:    `23`
- Expected output is: `23,1000`

Comment: Here's your problem: `list1.get(x)==list1.get(y)` . use `list1.get(x).equals(list1.get(y))` instead.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much, it works! You're my savior!!!!

Answer (score 3):

To add an explanation to the existing answers:

In Java there are two ways of comparing *things* - `==` and `equals`, where the latter is required for comparing objects (short version, for details see [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/4616087)). So the correct way of comparing two `Integer`s is indeed `x.equals(y)`.

The reason why your output still contained "23" is Java's integer cache. The [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) explicitly requires that `x == y` is true for all numbers between -127 and +128 (also short version, for details see 
[Integers caching in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3131136/4616087)).

Short demo:

```
Integer a1 = 23;
Integer a2 = 23;
Integer b1 = 1000;
Integer b2 = 1000;
System.out.println(a1 == a2);      // true
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // true
System.out.println(b1 == b2);      // false
System.out.println(b1.equals(b2)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your manipulating `Integer`, they are object, you may compare them with `.equals()` not `==` that check for reference

Set this, and it'll be ok  :

```
if (list1.get(x).equals(list1.get(y))) {
    list2.add(list1.get(x));
}
```

Also, to look on a `List` indexes, use `x < list1.size()` instead of `x <= list1.size() - 1`, you can also use for-each

```
for (Integer integer : list2) {
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` for comparison instead of `==`

```
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    list1.add(23);
    list1.add(1000);
    list1.add(1000);
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(23);
    List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int x = 0; x <= list1.size()-1; x++) {
        for(int y = x+1; y <= list1.size()-1; y++) {
            if(list1.get(x).equals(list1.get(y)) {
            list2.add(list1.get(x));
        }
    }
}

for(int y = 0; y <= list2.size()-1; y++) {
    System.out.println(list2.get(y));
}
```