# When does Integer != 1 come true

Tags: java

This is classical, but writing to Google did not give me hits.

**My code:**

```
Integer i = ..; // Sth is put from database.
if (i != 1) {
   // do sth
} else {
   // do not.
}
```

**Case:**

I know that this comparison is not correct `java` and I should compare:

```
if (i.intValue != 1) {}
```

or

```
if(!i.equals(1)) {}
```

but my code had the first one and I seem to get the true from somewhere, where the `Integer` is not 1 and when it is 1 there comes false.

**Question:**

What is happening there around?

Comment: One word, autoboxing... `Integer` will be automatically converted to `int` when needed.

Comment: Integers are autounboxed

Comment: Please be aware, however, that autounboxing does not come in play in some cases when doing a `reference comparison`. See this question for more info: [Comparing Integer Values in Java, Strange Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002037/comparing-integer-values-in-java-strange-behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *but my code had the first one and I seem to get the true from somewhere, where the Integer is not 1 and when it is 1 there comes false.*

If I understand your issue correctly, the following might explain the behavior:

```
Integer i = 1;
Integer j = new Integer(1);
Integer k = Integer.valueOf(1);

System.out.println(i == j);  // false
System.out.println(i == k);  // true
```

In other words, you can get both true or false when comparing with `1` depending on how the `Integer` was constructed. `Integer.valueOf` will reuse objects while `new Integer` will not.

If you indeed did the comparison with an integer literal (or with an `int`) then any `Integer` should be automatically unboxed by the compiler, and you should never get any surprises.

Comment: Sth like this may be there, because this part of code was working just opposite to my common sense and thus I had to ask sillies.

Comment: Yeah. Autoboxing has bitten me many times. (For instance when trying to look up a value in a `Map<Integer, String>` while accidentally providing a `Long` as key, thinking it would convert it to an integer.)

Comment: I also remembered some notation that == with two Integer somehow compare the object, not value. Like pointed in your and other answers, this is not the case always, though.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler changes :

```
if (i != 1)
```

to

```
if(i.intValue()!=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

[See this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 1):

`if (i != 1)` , `if (i.intValue != 1)` and `if(!i.equals(1))` are all equal and will return the same value. The compiler will automatically unbox `i`, turning it into a primitive `int`.