# Why Comparison Of two Integer using == sometimes works and sometimes not?

Tags: java, types, comparison

I know that i am comparing reference while i'm using == which is not a good idea but i did not understand why is this happening.

```
Integer a=100;
Integer b=100;
Integer c=500;
Integer d=500;
System.out.println(a == b); //true
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //true
System.out.println(c == d); //false
System.out.println(c.equals(d)); //true
```

Comment: yeah it's duplicate!! i got perfect answer form here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002037/comparing-integer-values-in-java-strange-behavior. Thank you all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Java Language Specification says that the wrapper objects for at least -128 to 127 are cached and reused by `Integer.valueOf()`, which is implicitly used by the autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Integers between -128 and 127 are cached (Integers of the same value reference the same `Object`). Comparing your `a` and `b` references returns `true`, because they are the same `Object`. Your `c` and `d` are not in that range, so their reference comparison returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer values  between -128 to 127 are being cached.

See the below Source code:

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    private IntegerCache(){}

    static final Integer cache[] = new Integer[-(-128) + 127 + 1];

    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
            cache[i] = new Integer(i - 128);
    }
}

public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache 
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
    }
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: a == b returns true means a and b references the same object. c == d returns false means c and d are not the same objects (even if their intValue are the same)

Comment: Yes absolutely correct Mastov.... Initially i got confused too... Please delete irrelevant comments regarding to this post. Thanks you all

Comment: Just for closing this thread (And I was highlighting a little bit hard), is something very important from [choosen response in duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002037/comparing-integer-values-in-java-strange-behavior) : **Moral: don't compare Integer references when you're interested in the underlying int values. Use .equals() or get the int values first.**

Comment: Yes, but that was clear to everyone, it's even stated in the question!