# i am getting true and false output why?

Tags: java, object, integer, primitive

I know `int` range is `-2147483648` to `+2147483647` but here I'm getting output as `true` and `false`. Why? Actually `i1` and `i2` point to the same object, so output is `true`. I can understood but `i3` and `i4` also pointing to same object but I got output as `false`. Why?

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i1 = 127;
        Integer i2 = 127;
        System.out.println(i1 == i2);
        Integer i3 = 128;
        Integer i4 = 128;
        System.out.println(i3 == i4);
    }
}
```

the output is

```
true

false
```

why output should be like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002037/comparing-integer-values-in-java-strange-behavior#10002084

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `Integer` object. For `Integer` object, values in between `-128 to 127` are pooled

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the difference between `==` and `equals`. `==` just tests to see if two `Integer` variables point to the *same* object, which could be either `true` or `false` depending on the implementation of your JVM. `equals` actually tests to see if they hold the same *value*. So in this case, you'll want to use `equals`:

```
// ...
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2));
// ...
System.out.println(i3.equals(i4));
```