# When comparing two equal integers in while loop, the equal-to operator fails?

Tags: java, android, break, comparison-operators

I've posted two examples below.
In the first example, I use the **equal-to** operator and the while process continues forever instead of breaking when it should.
In the second example, I use the **greater-than-or-equal-to** operator, and the process breaks when it should.
How is this even possible?

EXAMPLE 1:

```
  Integer myVar1 = 42985;
  Integer myVar2 = 1;
  while (true)
  {
     if (myVar2 == myVar1)
     {
     break;
     }

  ++ myVar2;
  }
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
  Integer myVar1 = 42985;
  Integer myVar2 = 1;
  while (true)
  {
     if (myVar2 >= myVar1)
     {
     break;
     }

  ++ myVar2;
  }
```

EDIT:
Thank you everyone for the great answers!
I fully understand the problem now and this new information explained several strange behaviors that I've encountered in my apps.
I wish I could choose more than one best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the less pleasant effects of auto-boxing.

In your first example, the `==` operator indicates identity equality: the two objects will only be equal if they are the same instance.

In your second example, the '>=' operator indicates numeric comparison: the two objects will be auto-unboxed and then compared.

Making things more confusing, there's a range of "small" integers (-128 <= X <= 127, iirc) for which the JVM caches `Integer` values, so the `==` operator *sometimes* works.

Bottom line: use `.equals()` and `.compareTo()`.

Comment: Are there any cases in which I would want to use the '==' operator or should I just stop using it altogether? Also, what about the '!=' operator? Does it have the same flaw?

Comment: @EricGlass - as I said, use `.equals()` and `.compareTo()`. The *only* time that you should use `==` with objects is when you're explicitly testing for object identity (which I find I rarely do).

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use `.equals()` to compare the value of two objects.

Anytime you use `==` it will compare instances of objects.  `.equals()` is a method inherited from `Object` and is used to compare the values of objects.

Answer (score 3):

`>=` does not work with objects, only numerics. The `Integer`s are unboxed into `ints` which can be compared properly.

When using `==` no unboxing occurs and therefore the references are compared. This is never guaranteed to compare the values.

You can use:

```
(myVar2.equals(myVar1))
```

Answer (score 3):

In the EXAMPLE 1, when you use the operator `==` with two `Integer` you are comparing their positions in memory, because `Integer` is a class and variables `myVar1` and `myVar2` are objects and they are not unboxed in two `int` primitives, whereas in the EXAMPLE 2, when you use the operator `>=` the two `Integer` objects are unboxed and the process breaks when it should.
You can use the operator `equals`:

```
Integer myVar1 = 42985;
Integer myVar2 = 1;
while (true) {
    if (myVar2.equals(myVar1)) {
        break;
    }


    ++myVar2;
}
```

Or you can try the method `intValue()`:

```
Integer myVar1 = 42985;
Integer myVar2 = 1;
while (true) {
    if (myVar2.intValue() == myVar1.intValue()) {
    break;
}

++myVar2;
}
```

If a `Integer` object value is equal or less than 127 the operator `==` will work:

```
Integer myVar1 = 127;
Integer myVar2 = 1;
while (true) {
    if (myVar2 == myVar1) {
        break;
}


++myVar2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the intValue() suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `equals` when you compare 2 objects.

if you still want to use `>=` then auto-unbox (de-autobox) `myvar1` and `myvar2`:

```
if (myVar2.intValue() >= myVar1.intValue())
```

**A simple best practice for auto-boxing in Java: Wrapper classes should only be used whenever you absolutely cannot use a primitive.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the intValue() suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing if the references are the same here, you are not comparing primitive types:

```
if (myVar2 == myVar1)
```

You should use `equals` to compare the values:

```
if (myVar2.equals( myVar1 ) )
```

For the `>=` case, this won't work with an `Object` so it will unbox the values and work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Autounboxing occurs when you use the `>=` but does not when comparing with `==` use `equals`for comparing the objects

I recommend you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953180/integer-value-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for comparing :

```
 Integer myVar1 = 42985;
 Integer myVar2 = 1;
 while (true)
{
 if (myVar2.equals(myVar1))
 {
 break;
 }

++ myVar2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the 'int' type is a primitive , whereas the 'Integer' type is an object.

so to compare objects use equals() method

**so either use :**

```
 Integer myVar1 = 42985;
 Integer myVar2 = 1;
 while (true)
  {
    if (myVar2.equals(myVar1))
     {
      break;
     }

     ++ myVar2;
  }
```

**or** declare it using **int**

```
int myVar1 = 42985;
 int myVar2 = 1;
 while (true)
  {
    if (myVar1==myVar2)
     {
      break;
     }

     ++ myVar2;
  }
```